# SQL to include condition in Where if not null

Tags: sql, ms-access, subform

In access I have been trying to set up user filters on what is displayed in a subform which is a list of inspection. Other methods Ive tried looking into have not been working but I have success with the below code,   It will filter if a user fills any other the filter options.  What I can figure out is how to have it accept multiple filters unless I spelt out every possible combination of boxes

So is there anyway this is actually possible or do I need to look at other options?

```
WHERE [STATUS] = "OPEN" 
AND 
(ANY FORM FILTERS is not Null [Filter by all those that are not null to its matching column])
```

effectively is there any easy way to include a condition if a form filter is not null

```
SELECT Inspections.INS_ID
    ,Inspections.Category
    ,Inspections.Assigned_Officer
    ,Inspections.Raised_For
    ,Inspections.Account
    ,Inspections.Number
    ,Inspections.Street
    ,Inspections.Area
    ,Inspections.Postcode
    ,Inspections.Date_Raised
    ,Inspections.Reason
    ,Inspections.INS_Comments
FROM Inspections
WHERE (
        ((Inspections.STATUS) = "Open")
        AND (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_ID]) IS NULL)
        AND (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_account]) IS NULL)
        AND (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_officer]) IS NULL)
        AND (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_Number]) IS NULL)
        AND (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_Postcode]) IS NULL)
        AND (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_Category]) IS NULL)
        AND (
            (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_From]) IS NULL)
            AND (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_To]) IS NULL)
            )
        )
    OR (
        ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_ID]) IS NOT NULL
        AND ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_ID]) = [Inspections].[INS_ID]
        )
    OR (
        ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_account]) IS NOT NULL
        AND ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_account]) = [Inspections].[Account]
        )
    OR (
        ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_officer]) IS NOT NULL
        AND ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_officer]) = [Inspections].[Assigned_Officer]
        )
    OR (
        ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_Number]) IS NOT NULL
        AND ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_Number]) = [Inspections].[Number]
        )
    OR (
        ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_Postcode]) IS NOT NULL
        AND ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_Postcode]) = [Inspections].[Postcode]
        )
    OR (
        ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_Category]) IS NOT NULL
        AND ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_Category]) = [Inspections].[Category]
        )
    OR (
        (
            (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_From]) IS NOT NULL)
            AND (([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_To]) IS NOT NULL)
            )
        AND ([Inspections].[Raised_For]) BETWEEN (
                    ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_From])
                    AND ([Forms]![Manage_Open]![Filter_to])
                    ) )
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a form with several unbound controls that the user will fill in. You, then want to filter your subform according to what the user has entered.
In that case, the method you are trying to use will become very complex and difficult to maintain, not to mention slow with a lot of data.
The best bet is to build the filter in code.
What I often do is name the controls the same as the field name and put the field type in the control's tag property. Then loop through the controls to build the filter. This is air code, but should give you a start.

`Dim strFilter as string
Dim ctL as Access.control
For Each ctL in Me.Controls
If Not ISNull(ctL) And ctL.Tag <> "" Then
strFilter = strFilter & " AND " & ctl.Name & " = "
If ctL.Tag = "Text" Then
strFilter = strFilter & "'" & Replace(ctl, "'","''") & "'"
ElseIf ctL.Tag = "Date" Then
strFilter = strFilter & "#" & ctl & "#"
Else
strFilter = strFilter & ctlEnd If
Next
If strFilter <> "" Then
strFilter = mid(strFilter, 6)
strFilter = " Where " & strFilter
End If
Me.yourSubForm.Form.Recordsource = "Select * From <yourQuery> " & strfilter`

Comment: Ok ive got this working for the most part, well I've gained an understanding of how it works but I still haven't got it filtering on this method,  I think my problem is "put the field type in the control's tag property" Ive never used tags and feel silly but is this meaning to add the field type as in text, date, autonumber ect to the Smart tags property under DATA on each filter box (control) ?

Comment: Also If I didn't want to pull from a query I could change "Select * From <yourQuery> " to " Select <fields> From <Table>  couldn't I ?  the reason for this is I want 2 fields on the displayed subform to be directly editable to its record and it seems the easiest way without doing separate writes when I don't need to here

Comment: Using the Tag property serves two purposes. First, when looping through the controls, only those with a Tag entry are looked at and utilized. Second, when building the filter, the code needs to know the field type, in order to determine whether or not to add text or date qualifiers. If you are not familiar with the forms' controls collection or the Tag property, I suggest you do a bit of research. The code generates a WHERE clause and can be used along with any SELECT clause for your recordsource. <yourQuery>, like the rest, is an example. You'll need to work out your specific details.

Comment: I feel a complete fool, I thought I had full understanding of the filtering VBA and set up properly It just wasn't applying any filters, turned out it was just that I hadn't set the tags properly putting it in DATA-smart tag instead of OTHER-tag.  spent half the day trying to get this working and when it was the simplest thing.  still ive gained knowledge. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help. If this solves your issue, you should mark it as answer.