# Access VBA or Any

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to have multi search boxes in my database search form, that I should sort the data like:

`where IdNumber=12, year=2017, codnumber=022004, Positiontitle=Director, Directorate=Audit` or etc ...)

but this search code is for one search box and multi fields and I want multi search box multi fields.

```
Private Sub Command379_Click() 

    Dim StrText As String
    Dim StrSearch As String
    Dim Task As String
    Dim strProgram As String

    If IsNull(Me.txtsearch) Or Me.txtsearch = "" Then
     '  MsgBox "Please type a word in search.", vbOKOnly, "Type a Word"
        Me.txtsearch.BackColor = vbYellow
        'Me.txtsearch.setfouc
    Else
        StrSearch = Me.txtsearch.Value
        Task = "SELECT * FROM Gneraltable where((Office like ""*" & StrSearch & "*"")or (year like ""*" & StrSearch & "*"")))"'
        'Me.RecordSource = Task
        'Me.txtsearch.BackColor = vbtransparent'
        'Me.RecordSource = StrSearch'
    'End If'
    'End'
```

[For each fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwdeR.png)

[image]

Comment: See if this helps http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Here is an efficient option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654449/sql-to-include-condition-in-where-if-not-null/44655836?noredirect=1#comment76339797_44655836