# SQL search form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Very new to SQL in that I have never used it! I am currently writing a query in Access but have come across errors saying the query is too complex and so thought writing directly in SQL may solve it.

I have a very simple table of data and am creating a search form with multiple criteria. These include searching for names and streets and also searching between dates and figures, or greater and lower than the ones entered by users, (Greater and lower are achieved using VBA on the form, a drop down menu and a between search, when the user selects lower from the drop down menu VBA puts a date or figure lower than any in the data table in the first 'Between' textbox and the user enters a date or figure in the second and for greater it is the opposite).

I am trying to write what I think will be a where clause, where the query looks for the value in the dropdown menu on the form and if it doesn't match, to then apply that part of the query if it does, then skip that part.

What I have so far is below, but to be honest I have no idea if it's remotely correct!

```
SELECT tblFOIData.Start_Date_of_Liability
FROM tblFOIData
WHERE ((([Forms]![frmSearch]![cmbStartDate_CriteriaSlection]<>"";
(tblFOIData.Start_Date_of_Liability) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_Start_Date_1] And [Between_Start_Date_2])));
```

I have been working on this for hours so if this isn't the best way to do it and someone can recommend an easier way to create a search form with the ability to enter 20 search criteria at the same time. (6 of which are wildcard searches and 14 need to be between searches), I would be very grateful to hear your suggestions.

UPDATE:

After looking more I have come up with this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblFOIData

WHERE (((tblFOIData.Area_Ref) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Area_Ref) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![cmbBilling_Authority] & "*") 
AND ((Nz([tblFOIData]![Ratepayer],"")) Is Null Or (Nz([tblFOIData]![Ratepayer],"")) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![Rate_Payer] & "*") 
AND ((tblFOIData.Scheme_Reference) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Scheme_Reference) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![Scheme_Ref] & "*") 
AND ((tblFOIData.Account_Mailing_Address) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Account_Mailing_Address) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![Account_Mailing] & "*") 
AND ((tblFOIData.Empty_Prop) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Empty_Prop) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![Empt_Prop] & "*") 
AND ((tblFOIData.Charity) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Charity) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![Charity] & "*") 
AND ((tblFOIData.SBRR) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.SBRR) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![SBRR] & "*") 
AND ((tblFOIData.Address) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Address) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![Address] & "*") 
AND ((tblFOIData.Postcode) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Postcode) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![Postcode] & "*") 
AND ((tblFOIData.Description) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Description) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmSearch]![Description] & "*")

AND ((tblFOIData.Start_Date_of_Liability) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Start_Date_of_Liability) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_Start_Date_1] And [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_Start_Date_2]) 
AND ((tblFOIData.[2017_RV]) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.[2017_RV]) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_2017_RV_1] And [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_2017_RV_2]) 
AND ((tblFOIData.[2017_Effective_From]) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.[2017_Effective_From]) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_2017_Effective_1] And [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_2017_Effective_2]) 
AND ((tblFOIData.[2017_Alteration_Date]) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.[2017_Alteration_Date]) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_2017_Alteration_1] And [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_2017_Alteration_2]) 
AND ((tblFOIData.Compiled_2017_RV) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Compiled_2017_RV) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_Compiled_RV_1] And [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_Compiled_RV_2]) 
AND ((tblFOIData.Percentage_Increase) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.Percentage_Increase) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_Percentage_Increase_1] And [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_Percentage_Increase_2]) 
AND ((tblFOIData.[2010_Rateable_Value]) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.[2010_Rateable_Value]) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_2010_RV_1] And [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_2010_RV_2]) 
AND ((tblFOIData.[2017_UAR_Current]) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.[2017_UAR_Current]) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_UAR_Current_1] And [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_UAR_Current_2]) 
AND ((tblFOIData.[2017_UAR_Historic]) Is Null Or (tblFOIData.[2017_UAR_Historic]) Between [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_UAR_Historic_1] And [Forms]![frmSearch]![Between_UAR_Historic_2]));
```

The first part works perfectly, but I get a 'too complex' error when I add the 'Between' searches.

I know this may not be the most effective way of performing this search but is there a way to make this work? I have a dropdown option on the form assigned to each of the 'Between' searches, is there a way to bypass the criteria if they do not select an optionfrom the dropdown, maybe with an if or case?

Comment: In your `WHERE` clause, remove the `;` from `<>"";` and replace with `AND`. The semi-colon is a statement terminator in SQL.

Comment: 20 criteria is a lot - can you not perform this in stages by reducing the returned recordset in "chunks" ? I would also have a read / download the sample here; http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Thanks Paul, that worked but it's not giving me the results I'm after for when there is nothing placed in cmbStart_Date_CriteriaSelection. When nothing is placed in their I want the query to bypass this step, maybe I need to put an If statement in?

Comment: Thanks Minty I will have a read through that. I was thinking it may be a bit too much in terms of criteria

Comment: @jufg, please post the corresponding full VBA code block that calls this SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create a complex SQL query that is different based on criteria in your form, is to create a string that you build in a number of steps, for example (simplified):

```
Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT tblFOIData.Start_Date_of_Liability FROM tblFOIData WHERE"

    If (((([Forms]![frmSearch]![cmbStartDate_CriteriaSlection]<>"") Then
        strSQL = strSQL + "Start_Date = tblFOIData.Start_Date_of_Liability "
    End If

    If (otherCriterium = True) Then strSQL = strSQL + "AND myCol = " + [myForm.value] + " "

    ' etc

    strSQL = strSQL + ";"

    ' now execute the query
```

After creating the string, you can print it for inspection.

Comment: Thanks Paul I will have a look and see if I can get this to work. Is this place in a module like I would with VBA? Sorry if I'm asking stupid questions!

Comment: You can place it either in a module, or in the code of the form you use to collect the query information.

Comment: For action queries, I agree with this course of action, since you can also execute them through VBA. For select queries, if I go VBA, I usually use a user-defined function that does all checking and returns a boolean. OP, if you're interested, I can post an example on how to do this.

Comment: Hi Erik, if you could post an example that would be great as I'm not too sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

A query like that quickly becomes very complex, difficult to writ and maintain.
For search forms, I typically loop through all of the controls and build the where clause from the result. It's much cleaner.
See my answer to a similar question here:
[SQL to include condition in Where if not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44654449/sql-to-include-condition-in-where-if-not-null/44655836#44655836)